# Circle drawn on canvas isn't round

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have problem creating simple circle. I think code drawing it is writed like it suposed to be, and another problem is with axis. I dont know why but 0x point begins in the middle of the "game screen". How to make game screen 640px/480px?

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ae3nj03a/1/)** | **[Screenshot](http://pl.tinypic.com/r/wce0k8/8)**

```
start.wyswietl = (function(){
var dom = start.dom,
    $ = dom.$,
    gracz = start.gracz,
    canvas, ctx,
    pUruchomienie = true;

function createBackground(){
    var background = document.createElement("canvas");
    bgctx = background.getContext("2d");
    dom.dodKlase(background, "background");
    background.width = 640;
    background.height = 480;
    background = new Image();
    background.onload = function(){
        bgctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);

    };

    background.src = "../obrazki/tapeta.png";
    dom.dodKlase(background, "board-bg");
    return background;
}

function rysuj(callback){
    var gracz = document.createElement("canvas");
    gctx = gracz.getContext("2d");
    gctx.fillStyle = "black";
    gctx.arc(5, 40, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    gctx.fill();
  //  dom.dodKlase(gracz, "plansza");
    dom.dodKlase(gracz, "gracze");
    return gracz;
    callback();
}

 //function ()
```

Comment: jsfiddle is not showing anything, even it does not show the screenshoot you attached above.

Comment: jsfiddle bug `Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined`

Comment: sry but i have many modules and dont know where to place others. If u know where to place the plz give me a hint

Comment: @KarolSz, You really need to reform your question to show a concise example of what's going wrong and to ask what you need more clearly. My wild guess is that you are resizing the canvas using CSS which will distort the canvas content if not resized proportionally.

Comment: Thats,why i uploaded jsfiddle. Im trying to create game screen with size 640px/480px but my function "wyswietl()" -( where i want to draw components) doesn't have this resolution. point 0x in axis isnt in the top left corner but on the top-middle of the screen.. If u can tell me where can i upload file, ill do it cose i dont know how to show all my project

Comment: here is link to my project, http://www.filedropper.com/obronawiezy the class wyswietl  isnt working like it should i think